# SQL Query Limit=4 gives me 16 records instead of 4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

This question applies to PHP, MySQL query and an AJAX program being called to display a LIMIT of 4 records using a MySQL Query. Instead it displays 16 recods.

---

The main program is PHP.
It calls AJAX from Javascript(every 120 seconds using a Javascript timer loop).

I have a MySQL Query inside the AJAX program(written also in PHP). 
This is supposed to limit output to 4 records (there are about 80 in the table).

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM chat  order by chat_RecordId desc limit 4";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
```

this is followed by a PHP loop inside the AJAX program which iterates through the table records found.

```
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
    ...code to print one record eg...
    echo mysql_result($result,$i,"chat_RecordId") ;
    $i++;
}
```

$num is 4. verified.
the loop excutes 4 times. verified.

but instead of displaying only 4 records in total on my screen(output is in a TEXTAREA inside a DIV in the main program) it displays 16 records = 4 x 4, which is is incorrect.

in fact, each group of 4 records is REPEATED 3 additional times with the SAME 4 records being displayed.

I cannot see a reason why 16 records are displayed and not 4 records only.

I should point out that the program being executed is an AJAX program.
And, the AJAX is called by a Javascript function inside the PHP program, The JS runs on a timer and calls the AJAX every 120 seconds using a Javascript Form. 
This is to refresh the website with new postings automatically.
By the way, the call to AJAX uses:

code which calls AJAX (not entire code but key lines)

```
var xmlhttp ;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
document.getElementById("txtChat").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.send();
```

Thanks all.

Comment: use mysqli_* functions. usage of mysql_* functions not recommended

Comment: `mysql_result()` is VERY inefficient. You should be using a conventional `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { echo $row['chat_recordID']; }` thing instead.

Comment: And not sure if it's a typo in your orig statement but the function is mysql_num_rows($result) not mysql_numrows as you typed. Good luck.

Comment: If all 4 groups are identical you probably have an outside loop around this loop, so this loop is being called 4 times, instead of once.